# How to write Docker logs to a file in real time (à la `tail -f`)

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, docker, tail

I docker that output logs stdout stderr, which can be viewed using:

```
docker logs -f $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID
```

I also added 'sed', which puts the container id on each line:

```
docker logs -f $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID | sed "s/^/$LOGS_CONTAINER_ID /"
```

If I run it, I get something like:

```
container112 error 10:20:10 problem
container112 info 10:20:09 not problem
container112 error 10:20:01 problem
```

where "container112" is $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID.

SO FAR SO GOOD. Now I want to output the above command to a file (log.out),
so I wrote the following command:

```
docker logs -f $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID | sed "s/^/$LOGS_CONTAINER_ID /" >> log.out
```

What happens is that it writes the logs to log.out, but it doesn't get new logs (if I open a new session and run `tail -f log.out`, I don't get output).
So I also tried:

```
tail -f $(docker logs -f $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID | sed "s/^/$LOGS_CONTAINER_ID /") >> log.out
```

But it also didn't work.
What is the problem?

Comment: Why would it have the new logs? Are you running something in the background? Your `docker logs` command only runs once. If you want more logs, you need to run it again.

Comment: if I just run "docker logs -f $LOGS_CONTAINER_ID  >> log.out", and on another session I run "tail -f log.out", I get new logs.

Comment: If you do `docker inspect $CONTAINER_ID | grep log` then you'll find a pathname where docker writes its logs to.  You may be able to use that

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/577865/9447571, see if making `sed` unbuffered (either using `-u` or the `stdbuf` helper command) will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

`docker logs $CONTAINERID 2>&1 | cat > logfile.log`

Comment: Perhaps `docker logs $CONTAINERID > logfile.log 2>&1`?